# SDWebImage Apple Mach-O Linker Warning

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

Recently I have successfully installed my SDwebImage to my project and it works absolutely fine. But however, there is an issue that annoys me. I tried to reinstall my SDWebImage framework but I still get the same warning. Just to note in have added my framework in Build Phrases and imported SDWebImage to the relevant files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v67YW.png)

Comment: close project and open workspace. if you have install cocoapod recently.

Comment: or Click on your project (targets)
->Build Settings ->
Under "Library Search Paths", delete the paths ->
Clean your build and run again.

Comment: if you are using cocoapod. first remove SDWebImage from podfile. and run command pod install. after add another time. and run command pod install. It will working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1.  Click on your project (targets) 
2.  Click on Build Settings 
3.  Use the arrows next to your project name (right above the Basic and All buttons) the change to the Tests target 
4.  if the warning is ...for option '-F/... thats Framework Search Paths, delete the stuff there
5.  Clean 
6.  Build Go for it.
```